# How to not allow the user to enter a value more than 190 in uitextfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have to allow values less than 190 in `uitextfield` while entering itself.we should not allow user to enter `1` to `9` digits after `19`.

Can anyone please provide me some info regarding this.
I tried the below code.But it's allowing more than `190`.

```
if countElements(textField.text!) + countElements(string) - range.length < 4
{
    var floatValue : Float = NSString(string: toString(textField.text)).floatValue

    return floatValue < 190.0
}
```

Comment: If the user enters a number greater than 190 you could replace the value with 190? `if([textField.text intValue] > 190){textField.text = @"190";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How i would do it is set the the uiviewcontroller containing the uitextfield as the delegate of the text field.  Then add this:

```
//If number of characters needs to be less than 190
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([newString length]>190){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

//If value needs to be less than 190
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
    replacementString:(NSString *)string   
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([newString intValue]>190){
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This will limit the text to 190 characters, not to a value of <=190. Plain wrong.

Comment: That's not true.  If the new string is greater than 190 characters, then it won't allow the change.  Otherwise it will allow it.  You're wrong :)

Comment: OP wants to allow the texts "1" ... "190". But not "191" or "200".

Comment: I taught it was a Swift question

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification and then do the value check in the selector for the notification. Here is an example of implementation I verified in Xcode:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.textField.delegate = self;
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange
{
    if ([self.textField.text length] > 3) {
        NSString* subString = [self.textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
        self.textField.text = subString;
    }
    if ( [self.textField.text intValue] > 190)
    {
        NSString* subString = [self.textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
        self.textField.text = subString;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: BTW The OP is asking how to do it using Swift

Answer (score 0):

// set a tag of your textfield to 1
// in code below "yourtextfield" replace it with your text field reference name

```
 public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if textField.tag == 1  {
        let newLength = (textField.text?.utf16.count)! + string.utf16.count - range.length
        if newLength >= 3 {
            
            let newstr = (textField.text ?? "") + string
            if let value = Int(newstr), value > 109 {
                self.yourtextfield.text = ""
                self.yourtextfield.placeholder = "Enter lesser than or equal to 109"
                return false
            }else
            {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```