# Detecting if the user is typing?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitextfield, ios8.2

For a UITextField, what is the best way to detect if the user is typing and the textfield has a value?

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

- Value Changed: no response
- Editing Did End: no response
- Touch Up Inside: doesn't trigger until after the user clicks out of the textfield

Comment: UITextFieldDelegate methods?

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Comment: @user100002: doesn't work with iOS8 and Swift.

Comment: This works better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916943/how-to-not-allow-the-user-to-enter-a-value-more-than-190-in-uitextfield.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29045440/2303865

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` event.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, 
           shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
           replacementString string: String) 
 -> Bool {
  // Put your code here
}
```

This is called whenever a user adds or removes a new character to your `UITextField`.

If you want to accept the change, `return true`. Otherwise `return false`.

Just make sure your UITextField conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` Protocol